# How to remove the 1. when differentiating 0.5x^2

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

My question is very basic, When using the Differentiate functionality of Mathematica in this way:

```
D[0.5 x^2, x]
```

This results in:

```
1.x
```

I don't need the 1. but how can I tell mathematica to remove this? It works further along in my code and gives me results like:

```
{{1. m, 0, 0}, {0, 1. m, 0}, {0, 0, 1. Jcm}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the possibility to enter fractional values beforehand?

```
D[(1/2) x^2, x]
```

which gives

```
x
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Rationalize:

```
Rationalize[D[0.5 x^2, x]]
```

> x

```
Rationalize[{{1. m, 0, 0}, {0, 1. m, 0}, {0, 0, 1. Jcm}}]
```

> {{m, 0, 0}, {0, m, 0}, {0, 0, Jcm}}

Answer (score 0):

```
expr1 = D[0.5 x^2, x]
expr2 = D[0.25 x^4, x]

(* 1. x  *)

(* 1. x^3  *)
```

Then

```
    expr1[[2]]
    expr2[[2]]

  (*  x *)

  (*  x^3  *)
```